# Map as return type of @MatrixParameter

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

The Rest-api we are building we need some sort of filtering system to prevent too much (useless) data to be transfered to our client. The use of @MatrixParameter seems like a nice solution since this allows a readable way to filter on multiple 'levels' of the URI

However in our api we have fields our clients would like to filter on which are not defined on compile time (and can be different per client). This makes is infeasable to speficy these fields on the @matrixParam annotation.

So i was hoping there would be some way to use a Map as receiving 'bean' object

ie: when i do a GET on

> https://api.example.com/rest/filtered_get;param1=value1;param2=value2/optional/continuation/of/uri/

would end up with in map containing param1,param2 as keys and value1 and value2 as values

```
@Get()
@Path("filtered_get")
public Response getter(@matrixParam("") HashMap<String, String/Object>parameters) {
    //doStuffWiththeParameters;
}
```

The Service is being implemented with cxf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have this figured out.

The trick is to use the PathSegment variable

usinge the code like so:

```
@Path("/filter{reference_to_pathParam}")
public RestEntityService<T> search(@PathParam("reference_to_pathParam") PathSegment p) {
MultiValuedMap<String,String> matrix = p.getMatrixParameters();
// doStuff with the matrix parameters
}
```

allows  you to use unspecified matrix parameters in your URI like:

> https://api.example.com/rest/../filter;field=value;field2=value2/rest/of/the/URI/

and get those fields in the matrix (map)

Note that i'm using a explicit pathsegment for this filter. This is because if i would use something like @path("/{filter}") as annotation it would interfere with other selectors using pathparameters.

Not marking this as answer yet because i dont know if there might be better/cleaner ways to do this.